# Using Html in a SQL table and retrieving it in a foreach statement

Tags: c#, razor-pages

I am having some issues with Html stored in a Sql table.

I am using font Awesome and storing the "i" tags in a table record so that each record may or may not have different set of tags depending on the case.

The problem is Html.DisplayFor does not "Display" it correctly.

In other words it looks like this:

`&lt;i class=&quot;fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-success&quot;&gt;&lt;/i&gt;&lt;i class=&quot;fa fa-money fa-stack-1x fa-inverse&quot;&gt;&lt;/i&gt;`

I cannot use Html.Raw because it does not work with Lambda expressions.

Is there a way around this?

The other option I have is to set a int for the records and do if statements to change them and only store the actual font Awesome class in the table.

That to me seems like to much and there has to be a way to do it without doing that.

So something like this:

```
@if (item.Type = 1)
{
  <span class="app-notification__icon">
    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
         <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-success"></i>
             <i class="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NotificationType)"></i>
    </span>
   </span>
 }
```

Seems silly to me to have to do it that way and for each different item.
Any input would be great. Thanks

Comment: I doubt you can use `DisplayFor` to show unencoded HTML while you can simply use `@Html.Raw(item.NotificationType)`. The only way to display HTML with HTML helper using lambda expression is creating custom helper which directly write to view page instead using encoded string.

Comment: I actually was just thinking of that. It does work. This is probably going to be a stupid question, but I am still learning. If this works, why use the Lambda expression or will a Html.DisplayFor not work without it?

Comment: If you take a look for `DisplayFor` source, you will see it uses `TemplateFor` as shown in [class definition](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/TemplateHelpers.cs). The reason is `MvcHtmlString` instance encodes the output HTML, while `@Html.Raw` simply returns unencoded HTML string.

Comment: Got it, thanks for your help!